# python OOP - child variable updating set parent

Tags: python, class

I have a parent class with 3 items in it. I am trying to create a child class that when called updates a set item in the parent class.

```
class NOS:

    def __init__(self):
    self.Bike = 0
    self.car = 0
    self.plane = 0


class buy(NOS):

    def __init__(self, mode):
        NOS.__init__(self)
        self.mode = mode


    def buy_comp(self, value):
        self.mode += value
```

if i called it like below

```
a = buy('bike')
a.buy_comp(4)
```

I am trying to get to a situation where bike would equal 4. The above did not work. Neither did the below where i tried to use buy as a function instead of a class.

```
def buy(self, mode, value):
    self.mode += value

a= NOS()
a.buy('bike', 5)
```

Here i got the error - AttributeError: 'NOS' object has no attribute 'bike'

Answer (score 0):

In the first example you posted, your child class "buy" is not actually a child class, because it is not inheriting from "NOS".

Not exactly sure what you're trying to achieve. Maybe this is helpful?

```
class Parent:

    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = "Parent Foo"

class Child(Parent):

    def __init__(self):
        Parent.__init__(self)

    def set_foo(self, new_foo):
        self.foo = new_foo


child = Child()
print(child.foo)
child.set_foo("New Foo")
print(child.foo)
```

Output:

```
Parent Foo
New Foo
```

EDIT - Oh, I think I get it now. Something like this maybe?

```
class NOS:

    def __init__(self):
        self.bike = 0
        self.car = 0
        self.plane = 0

class Buy(NOS):

    def __init__(self, item_name):
        NOS.__init__(self)
        self.item_name = item_name

    def buy_comp(self, amount):
        try:
            old_value = getattr(self, self.item_name)
        except NameError:
            # No such item exists
            pass
        else:
            setattr(self, self.item_name, old_value + amount)

a = Buy("bike")
print(a.bike)

a.buy_comp(4)
print(a.bike)
```

However, I think that if you're relying on getattr and setattr, there's bound to be a better way. I have a feeling that this may be an instance of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Can you tell us more about the actual use case? I'm sure there's a more elegant solution you could benefit from.

Comment: edited buy to include NOS. i am trying to create one function which will update any of the items (bike, car or plane) when called

Comment: @ben121 instead of repeating the obvious, please explain why you're trying to create such a function - IOW, what is the _real_ problem you expect to solve with this "solution".